# Eliminate meta tags "single" and "multiple"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-block-request

[single](/questions/tagged/single) and [multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple) look like prime examples of meta-tags to me. Shall we burninate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, these two are now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Your avatar's head a splode.

Answer (score 6):

A quick look at [single](/questions/tagged/single) shows that it should be part of a hyphenated tag like [single-player](/questions/tagged/single-player) (not sure of the benefit of this one though) or [single-quote](/questions/tagged/single-quote) for example.

So rather than just deleting it will need someone to go through and retag where appropriate.